# Post response does not have the expected data

Tags: c#

Here follows a simple action method of one of my controllers:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<dynamic> UnitTest()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    dynamic model1 = new ExpandoObject();
    model1.title = "foo";
    model1.body = "bar";
    model1.userId = 1;
    var request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model1);
    var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, 
        new StringContent(request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    return response;
}
```

I would expect `response` to include an object like

```json
{
  id: 101,
  title: 'foo',
  body: 'bar',
  userId: 1
}
```

According to https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder#how-to. Instead, response is an object with the following properties:

```
Content (empty)
StatusCode: 201
ReasonPhrase: "Created"
Version: 1.1
```

***What am I doing wrong?***

Comment: response is just simply the HTML response, which was 201..

Comment: Is there a Location header on the response? That is typical when you have created a resource as opposed to GETting a resource.

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 2.0 the original OP's code works with no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.Content` is stream content and you should read the stream first before return action.

```
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Complete action looks like;

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> UnitTest()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    dynamic model1 = new ExpandoObject();
    model1.title = "foo";
    model1.body = "bar";
    model1.userId = 1;
    var request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model1);
    var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, 
        new StringContent(request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return content;
}
```

Also, it could be better to deserialize returned json as known type.

Comment: Content may be empty by design. It is common to have no content when you have created a resource, but usually there will be a location header.

Comment: I have just tested it. There is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to read the content then deserialize it to object before passing back.

```
var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
return obj;
```

Comment: Content may be empty by design. It is common to have no content when you have created a resource, but usually there will be a location header.